# При создании файлов через Visual Studio сохраняет в ansi

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Мне требуется сохранить в `utf-8` что нужно поменять в настройках.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте [аддон ForceUTF8 (with BOM)](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jz5.ForceUTF8withBOM-18593).